# Не применяется свойство top к div блоку

Tags: html, css

Есть блок div с названием класса `penguin`, мне нужно опустить данный блок на 10% вниз от родительского блока, но свойство `top` не применяется.
 Пробовал на 2-х редакторах, sublime и brackets. Css стили подключены верно. 
  В чем может быть ошибка?

```
//HTML:
<body>
<div class="penguin"></div>
</body>
//CSS:
.penguin{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: grey;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
top: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.penguin{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="penguin"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, а можно пояснение, почему свойство top  не применяется к данному блоку?

Comment: @Aibolat Imangaliyev ссылка для ознакомления https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/45/run/1 там Вы найдете ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: спасибо большое, помогли!